# Model not saving to DB and rolling back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Rails 5.1
```

fw_export.rb model:

```
class FwExport < ApplicationRecord
  include Shared

  has_one :location

end
```

location.rb model:

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  include Shared

  belongs_to :fw_export

end
```

locations_controller.rb:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_location, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @location = Location.new
  end

  def create
    @location = Location.new(location_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.save
        format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Location was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @location }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  private
    def set_location
      @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    end

    def location_params
      params.require(:location).permit(:fw_exports_id, :city, :state, :country, :api_source)
    end
end
```

location migration file:

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :locations, id: :string do |t|
      t.string :fw_exports_id
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.string :country
      t.string :api_source
      t.timestamps
      t.index [:fw_exports_id], unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

From the console, if I try to do the following:

```
location_record = Location.new(
  :fw_exports_id => "fwexport.1510768198.5364478"
)
location_record.save
```

It is failing and rolling back:

```
[9] pry(main)> location_record = Location.new(
[9] pry(main)*   :fw_exports_id => "fwexport.1510768198.5364478"
[9] pry(main)* )
=> #<Location:0x0000000003e68888 id: nil, fw_exports_id: "fwexport.1510768198.5364478", city: nil, state: nil, country: nil, api_source: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[10] pry(main)> location_record.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
```

If I do:

```
Location.create!(fw_exports_id: "fwexport.1510768198.5364478")
```

I get:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Fw export must exist
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

## Solution:

Location belongs to FwExport, so the foreign key needs to be singular as in fw_export_id, not fw_exports_id

It worked when I made that chanve

Comment: In console, do your `location_record = Location.new(...)`. Then `location_record.valid?` (it probably will return false). Then, `location_record.errors.full_messages`.

Comment: Check the output of `location_record.valid?` and `location_record.errors`?  That may give you a clue about what is wrong.  You could also use `save!` to potentially get a more descriptive error message.

Comment: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)

Comment: did you try `Location.create!(fw_exports_id: "fwexport.1510768198.5364478")` to see the error?

Comment: You should add your stack trace to your question (not in comments). Also, FWIW, this: `:fw_exports_id => "fwexport.1510768198.5364478"` is less conventional than `fw_exports_id: "fwexport.1510768198.5364478"`. And, it saves you two key strokes. saved_key_strokes == :longer_life

Comment: try to use the shebang version of `create` or `save` to make Rails raise an error and you will directly see what validation is failing.

Comment: @wasif-hossain See the edit to the question

Comment: so the validation is all about making sure if `fw_exports_id` exists. If not, then you must have to create an `FwExport` record with `fw_exports_id` before linking this value in the `Location` record.

Comment: It does exist. I got that id from the DB. Should I be specifying the foreign key somewhere explicitly?

Comment: yes please go ahead and add the foreign key constraint in the `:locations` table

Comment: i guess you may need to use `column` option with `add_foreign_key` in a location migration: `add_foreign_key :locations, :fw_exports, column: :fw_export_id`

Comment: the foreign key is assumed to be `table_name.singularize + "_id"`. In your case, it should be `fw_export_id` instead of `fw_exports_id`

Comment: @wassef-hossain this is what I finally figured. I am making those changes now

Comment: Yes, that worked

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `location_record.errors.full_messages`
right after:

```
location_record = Location.new(:fw_exports_id =>"fwexport.1510768198.5364478")
location_record.save
```

Copy the output here

It might contains cause of the problem

Comment: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)